# How do I set up VPN for connecting from Nexus One to my home network?

Tags: nexus-one, cyanogenmod, vpn

I'd like to set up my handset to be able to VPN into my home network.

At home I have the [Buffalo WZR-HP-G300NH](http://www.buffalotech.com/products/wireless/wireless-n-routers-access-points/airstation-nfiniti-wireless-n-high-power-router-access-point-wzr-hp-g300nh/) wireless router running dd-wrt firmware. My handset is Nexus One running the latest (as of this writing) CyanogenMod7 ROM nightly build (Android version 2.3.4)

Preferably, I'd like a step-by-step guide on configuring OpenVPN on the router and on the handset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been interested in trying this for a little while, but for now I have just been using SSH.  The guide I've been eyeing on the subject is here, which is using [OpenVPN to DD-WRT on Android](http://www.coffeepowered.net/2010/11/21/mobile-and-secure-setting-up-openvpn-with-dd-wrt-and-android/).

It seems pretty straightforward.

Comment: Wow, this is exactly what I was looking for!  Thanks!